# PDO Prepare 2 tables in one query

Tags: php

I made a database with 2 tables (students, teachers).
Each one has 1 row. So I have a student and a teacher. Both of them have id=1 because inside each table I have a column called id which is Auto Increment.

I did a login page and I used these:

```
$sth_username = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, id FROM students WHERE name = :name UNION SELECT name, id FROM teachers WHERE name = :name");
$sth_username->bindParam(":name", $name);
$sth_password = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password, salt FROM students WHERE name = :name UNION SELECT password, salt FROM teachers WHERE name = :name");
$sth_password->bindParam(":name", $name);
```

I am able to login and the redirect to index.php. Inside index.php I have this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id");
    $sth->bindParam(":id", $_SESSION['id']);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print "Name: ".$result['name']."<br>";
    print "Nickname: ".$result['nickname']."<br>";
    print "Town: ".$result['town']."<br>";
    print "Adress: ".$result['adress']."<br>";
    print "E-Mail: ".$result['email']."<br>";
```

If I loggin as a student it shows me these informations Name Nickname etc ... 
I want to loggin as a teacher and see those stats from the teacher's row. (Teacher's) Name, (Teacher's) Nickname etc ... I don't know what to write inside `$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id");`to make that working. I tried UNION and INNER JOIN but it didn'w work properly. I'm sure it is a simple thing and I will be very happy if you will help me.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: The first think you should learn is that PHP and SQL are *different languages*—your question has nothing to with PHP. Apart from that, are you really saying that you don't know how to change `SELECT * FROM students` to gather data from `teachers`?

Comment: I want to put both students and teachers in the same query

Comment: So you want to change `SELECT name, id FROM students WHERE name = :name UNION SELECT name, id FROM teachers WHERE name = :name` to filter by `id` rather than `name`?

Comment: I want to do $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id UNION SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id=:id"); but when I do this those Name , Nickname etc are empty: Name: nothing Nickname: nothing etc even if I loggin as student or as a teacher. But if I do this $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id"); and loggin as student it gives me the info. The UNIOS doesn't work here

Comment: Are all of the columns in the same in both the students and teachers tables? A union will fail if the columns are not the same.

Comment: No ... I read that about UNION so it will not be useful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, UNIONs will fail if the columns in both tables are not the same, or a different count. What you can do to get around it is to find out which table the user is in, save it in the session, and then use that as a table name in your second query:

Login page:

```
$sth_username = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, id, 'students' AS role FROM students WHERE name = :name UNION SELECT name, id, 'teachers' AS role FROM teachers WHERE name = :name");

$_SESSION['role_table'] = $row['role']; // or whatever your row result variable is
```

Index page:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$_SESSION['role_table']} WHERE id = :id");
```